# How to create multidimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary from which I like to create a multidimensional array through c#.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in rptdata)
{
    string s2 = pair.Key;        
    int s1 =  pair.Value;

    // var ccdata1 = new[] { new object[] { "Item1", 1 }  };
    // object value = cdata1[s1,s1];                                         
}
```

I need to add code inside the foreach look so that it can create something like the following:

```
var ccdata = new[] { new object[] { "Item1", 1 }, new object[] { "Item2", 2 } };
```

Note that Item1,Item2 would come from str1 and 1,2 would come from int1.

I am not sure how to iterate though to populate the multidimensional object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one query like this.  [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) is pretty great at transforming data.  If you want to turn it into JSON afterwards you can use a library, something like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

```
var ccdata = rptdata
               .Select( i => new object[]{ i.Key, i.Value } )
               .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Where would this code go? Would it go inside of the loop? Can you put it with the existing code so that I can see what it looks like? Also, will the code you mentioned above create a multidimensional array? Also how do I assign the array to ccdata? Thanks in advance