# Need Sum from multidimensional array using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, multidimensional-array, sum

I have the following code:

```
var ccdata = dict1.Select(i => 
                          new object[] { i.Key, Int32.Parse(i.Value) }
                         ).ToArray();
```

I need to get the sum of all of the i.Value's. Please note this is a multidimensional object array.
i.Key is a string value and i.Value is a int value which needs to be summed up.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you putting the two into an object array, thereby boxing everything?

Comment: What `i.Value` is string? Why do you parse it, why isn't it initially a number?

Comment: if I.Value is already an int then int.Parse will not compile since it expects a string. Is it a string or an int?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Because when he asked [how to create a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788784/how-to-create-multidimensional-array-as-json-for-jqplot-chart-in-asp-net-mvc-c-s), I suggested doing it with Linq.  Looks like he didn't bother looking up what Linq is all about and hoped random code he gets from this site can be combined into a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dic.Sum(i => Int32.Parse(i.Value)); // if i.Value is string instead of just int

dic.Sum(i => i.Value); // if string
```

or

```
ccdata.Sum(i => (int)i[1]); // if i[1] is object instead of just int

ccdata.Sum(i => i[1]); // if int
```

Comment: The latter will fail to compile, as the compile-time type of `i[1]` is just `object`.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you're doing it in quite this way, but it's fairly easy to sum them...

```
int sum = ccdata.Sum(x => (int) x[1]);
```

It would be clearer and more efficient if you used:

```
var ccdata = dict1.Select(i => new { i.Key, Value = Int32.Parse(i.Value) })
                  .ToArray();
```

That way you end up with compile-time type safety *and* no boxing:

```
int sum = ccdata.Sum(x => x.Value);
```

(I'm assuming you actually want ccdata for some other reason. Otherwise, use abatishchev's solution and get rid of your existing code altogether.)

Answer (score 1):

i.Value is at the second position in your inner array.
So it should go like that:

```
var sum = cdata.Sum(arr => (int)arr[1]);
```